# Is there a way to suppress the `rustc_on_unimplemented` message when looking for implementations of another trait that has a blanket implementation?

Tags: types, compiler-errors, rust, traits

I have the following code:

```
#![feature(on_unimplemented)]

use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct S<T>(PhantomData<T>);

#[rustc_on_unimplemented(message = "T1 missing")]
trait T1 {}

trait T2 {}

#[rustc_on_unimplemented(message = "T2 missing")]
impl<T: T1> T2 for S<T> {}

fn main() {
    wants_t2(S::<u8>(PhantomData));
}

fn wants_t2<T: T2>(_: T) {}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ffb23d4e2651db441e9cd0e096190040&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015))

When compiling this, I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: T1 missing
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     wants_t2(S::<u8>(PhantomData));
   |     ^^^^^^^^ the trait `T1` is not implemented for `u8`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `T2` for `S<u8>`
note: required by `wants_t2`
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | fn wants_t2<T: T2>(_: T) {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to suppress the `rustc_on_unimplemented` for `T1` when looking for implementations for `T2`? Somehow like [`Try`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c0955a34bcb17f0b31d7b86522a520ebe7fa93ac/src/libcore/ops/try.rs#L18) filters for a method?

Comment: Even if you put the `#[rustc_on_unimplemented]` on the `T2` trait definition instead of the blanket impl, it still shows the "T1 missing" message. It _feels_ like a bug, though you can see why it might do that. But I'm not very familiar with this RFC - in fact I could only find the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29628) and not the RFC...

Comment: [Possibly related RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2397)